# Nginx: One server with multiple locations configured in different files

Tags: nginx

I want to serve multiple services behind a reverse proxy. Each service has its own location. To keep things organized and manageable, I want to provide each location in its own configuration file instead of having one file with all locations.

For now I created a single configuration file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00-server.con` with the following content:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name ...;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  include /etc/nginx/locations.d/*.conf;
}
```

and a new directory `/etc/nginx/locations.d` containg my location configuration files.
E.g. to serve grafana:

```
location /grafana/ {
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_pass       http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

The basic idea is to just keep throwing these location configuration files into the directory (`/etc/nginx/locations.d`) (I am using ansible to set up this 'server')

With the different location configuration files in place, I can reach the services with urls like

- http://foobar/grafana
- http://foobar/wiki
  ...

I wonder, is this a good idea? Is there an easier or maybe... more conform way to do this?

Kind regards and thanks in advance.